# how can i get values of RXlev sub , RxQual sub and TA(Timing Advance)

Tags: android, android-ndk

Am developing one simple application in Android..In that i get the RSSI and RSCP and EcNo Values in(Db) using the telephony manager service.

How can i get TA(Timing Advance) and Rxlev Sub values ..by Which service am getting the values???like as (Telephony Manager)

Comment: Did you got solution for TA. If yes please post it.